# Chances of winning a raffle

Tags: probability, percentages

If there are 75 tickets and one 1st prize the chance is 1/75 x 100 in percentage terms. If the number of tickets doubles to 150 but there are now two 1st prizes (first 2 tickets drawn) do the odds of winning a 1st prize increase, decrease or stay the same?

I think the maths is 1/150 x 100 = 0.66666 recurring 
Plus
1/149 x 100 = 0.67114
= 1.33781
Compared with
1/75 x 100 = 0.33333 recurring.

So yes better odds. Do I have my maths right?

Comment: What is mean by "first 2 tickets drawn"?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning in the first setting is $\frac{1}{75}$, that is true.

As I understand the game, you cannot win both prices in the second setting. The probability of having the first ticket that is drawn is 
$$p(\text{first ticket}) = \frac{1}{150}$$
The probability of being the person with the second ticket drawn is 
$$p(\text{second ticket}) = \frac{149}{150} \cdot \frac{1}{149} = \frac{1}{150}$$
because you must be one of the 149 persons not having the first ticket and the one person winning when the second ticket is drawn.

Putting it together you have a probability
$$ \frac{1}{150} + \frac{1}{150} = \frac{1}{75}$$
so your chances stay the same.

You could also think of it like this: The probability of not winning is
$$p(\text{neither the first nor the second ticket}) = \frac{149}{150} \cdot \frac{148}{149} $$
so the probability of winning becomes 
$$ 1 - \frac{149}{150} \cdot \frac{148}{149} = 1 - \frac{74}{75} = \frac{1}{75}. $$

Comment: Many thanks. The key question is if I have one ticket out of 75 with 1 prize are my chances the same with one ticket out of 150 and two first prize draws. I think I understand the answer to be the chances are identical. Many thanks.

Comment: @CharlieWestrope If you buy one ticket from $n$ in total and among the $n$ tickets there are $k$ that are linked with a prize then the probability on winning a prize is $\frac{k}{n}$. Every ticket with a prize has probability $\frac1{n}$ to become the ticket you buy. So the total probability that one of those tickets will become the ticket you buy is $\frac1n+\frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n=\frac{k}{n}$.

Comment: @drhab Well... I interpreted it like this: They draw a ticket. The probability that it is yours is $\frac{1}{150}$. Then they draw another one. This leads to the argument I gave.